# How to replace an user's authentication 'http.formLogin()' with a form that is on another frontend server?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Inside a class that extends `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`, I have this authencitation method. I store my users inside an Active Directory.

```
    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
        ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider adProvider
                = new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider("domain.com", "ldap", "ou, dc");
        adProvider.setConvertSubErrorCodesToExceptions(true);
        adProvider.setUseAuthenticationRequestCredentials(true);
        adProvider.setUserDetailsContextMapper(userDetailsContextMapper());
        auth.authenticationProvider(adProvider);
    }
```

I used to use a `http.formLogin()` for testing purpose. Whenever I call `localhost:80/security` I had to write my username and password in the form.

This method was perfect for testing my connexion to the AD.

But now, I have my frontend in a different server. So here is my question, where should I pass the username and the password to the authentication method ?

How can I hardcode the username and the password and authenicate to my Active Directory ? (for testing only now, after I'm going to use filters and controllers after).

I hope my question is clear.

Comment: I don't understand your question: what do you mean exactly with "now I have my frontend in a different server"? Did your frontend and backend before run _both_ on localhost? What is the situation now? Frontend runs no longer on localhost, but should access a backend that still runs on localhost? And what kind of testing do you want to perform, manual testing or automated testing? In the latter case: automated end-to-end testing?

Comment: @cyberbrain My backend and my frontend are 2 different apps in two differents server using two differents technologies (java spring for the backend and vuejs for the front-end). My goal is (from my frontend) to connect to my backend(from my frontend) the same way as I used to do with `http.formLogin()`.

Comment: so with formLogin your backend provided the form to login, but why can't you do this just in your frontend? What did you try already and what were your findings so far?

Comment: The reason I can't do it with my frontend is because I don't know how to get the username and the password and pass it to `AuthenticationManagerBuilder`. In my frontend I should call a request `login?username=test&password=test` and then I should get this info in my backend and pass it to  my  `configure` function to check if the user exists in my AD. But I have no clue how to do it.

Comment: Have a look at one of the many tutorials that come up when you search for "spring security login", the first one I found was https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-login and it looks quite OK - you don't have to follow it completely, but they explain in detail how to provide your own login form (and just because they serve it from the backend doesn't mean you also have to do that).

Comment: Under the chapter `3.3. Configuration for Form Login`, they said this : `loginPage() – the custom login page` and in the example they gave this : `http.loginPage("/login.html")` . In this case, the `/login.html` should be in the same server as the backend (example : `mybackend.com/login.html`). But in my case, this login html page is here : `www.afrontendpage.com/login.html`. So, what should I do ? change the value given like this : `http.loginPage("www.afrontendpage.com/login.html.")` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have mixed two different questions: How to create outer login page and How to integrate your application with ActiveDirectory.

For single-page applications, your API should send a 200 response along with the user data, or a 4xx response. This can be done by supplying your own handlers, like this (pseudocode just show the idea):

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
http
    .formLogin()
        ...
        .successHandler(your authentication success handler object)
        .failureHandler(your authentication failure handler object)
        .and()
    .logout()
        ...
        .logoutSuccessHandler(your logout success handler object)
        .and()
    .exceptionHandling()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(new Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint())
    ...
}
```

For example, these are coded as below.

**Authentication success handler:**

```
@Component
public class AuthSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    @Autowired    
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Autowired    
    private MyService myService;

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, 
                    HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)
    throws IOException, ServletException {

        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);

        AbstractUser currentUser = myService.userForClient();

        response.getOutputStream().print(
            objectMapper.writeValueAsString(currentUser));

        clearAuthenticationAttributes(request);
    }
}
```

In summary, it returns a response code 200 with the JSONified current user in the response data.

**Authentication failure handler**

In fact, there is no need to code a class for the authentication failure handler - the `SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler` provided by Spring, if instantiated without any arguments, works as desired.

**Logout success handler**

```
public class MyLogoutSuccessHandler implements LogoutSuccessHandler {

    @Override
    public void onLogoutSuccess(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)
        throws IOException, ServletException {

          response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I still have one question before I try your solution. You wrote `http.loginForm`. As you guessed, I have an outer login page from an other server. In your code, how is the information sent from the outer login form to the application ?

Comment: No I wrote 'http.formLogin.' The default URL where the Spring Login will POST to trigger the authentication process is /login, which used to be /j_spring_security_check before Spring Security 4.

We can use the loginProcessingUrl method to override this URL:  http.formLogin() .loginProcessingUrl("/perform_login")

Comment: So, in my frontend server I have to do a POST request to `www.backend.com/login` and give it my username and password ?

Comment: Yep. And after that, you must check the user and password on the server-side in your auth service